# Multiple ajax generated input with datepicker having month and year only

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

I want to get multiple input boxes with `dateRange`, having month & year only using **ajax** technology.

In my project I need to get more than one input boxes dynamically from ajax call. And every input box should have daterange `drop-down` calendar only having option for selecting month and year.

On the same page (`abc.php`) it is working fine with the the below code:

```
 <input type="text" name='startMonth' class="monthyear" />

 <link href="../asset/datepicker3/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="../asset/datepicker3/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I'm calling from ajax it gets no response, code is as follows:

`abc.php`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="getInputBoxes()">Get Input Boxes</button>
<div id="block_input"></div>
<script>
    function getInputBoxes(){
            $.post('ajx_abc.php', { }, 
        function(data, status){
                    $('#block_input').html(data);
                    $("#block_input").html(data).find(".monthyear").datepicker();
            });
    }
</script>
```

Ajax file (`ajx_abc.php`):

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    <input type="text" name="cust_mnth[]" class="monthyear" />
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got it ! :)**

Need to pass only two parameters `minViewMode` & `format`

`abc.php`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="getInputBoxes()">Get Input Boxes</button>
<div id="block_input"></div>
<script>
    function getInputBoxes(){
            $.post('ajx_abc.php', { }, 
        function(data, status){
                    $('#block_input').html(data);
                    $("#block_input").html(data).find(".monthyear").datepicker({
                        minViewMode: 1,// 0-normal date calendar; 1-month; 2-year
                        format: 'yyyy-mm',
                        startDate: "0m", // from current month
                        endDate: "+2m" // till next 2 months
                    });
            });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Populate all of your input datepickers first.
Then initialize them;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).find("#block_input .monthyear").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Nops! :( displaying whole calendar including date as earlier. But I need only month and year.